# Uses of the tempfile module

Tags: python, temporary-files

Could someone tell me the benefit of a `tempfile` in python, and in which case should I use it?

I'm coding a program to process a file, and it will first call another script to process the file first, generating a temporary file and do next step which I'll code myself.

I'm wondering if I write the temporary file directly to disk using `fh.write()` and then after whole program delete them, or I should use `tempfile` module to create a `tempfile` to store it?

Comment: Basically, tempfile does the creation of a file with a unique name in /tmp, and then deletes it, all under the cover (less work for you).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and is there a way in python that write some in RAM but I can manipulate it as a file or file handle?

Comment: `from io import StringIO`, then do `StringIO("your data")`. The `StringIO` class acts just like a file (it has `read`, `write`, etc.) but is in RAM.

Comment: @matsjoyce, thanks very much, I think that what I want!

Comment: OK, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tempfile.html) module allows a script to create temporary files and directories. It handles all the boilerplate code dealing with creating a random, unique filename and deleting the file when the file object is no longer referenced. It is also cross-platform and portable, so there is no hassle when deciding where to put the file (`/tmp`, `./`, etc.).

If you want to create a temporary "file" in RAM, you can use [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html#io.StringIO) class from the [io](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html) module. You can initialise the "file" with the data (e.g. `StringIO("your data")`), and then it will act just like a file (with `read`, `write`, etc.).